# Como comparar contenido de dos HashMap y sustituir el valor de uno de ellos en android studio con java

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentado comparar el contenido de dos colecciones HasMap<String, String>(), y souy incapaz, pruebo una cosa y otra, y me van saliendo resultados, pero nunca el que deseo

Veamos:
Tengo ésta colección que almacena número de socio y nombre del socio

```
dataN = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    try {
        Statement stUs = miConexion.metodoConexionBD().createStatement();

        ResultSet ra = stUs.executeQuery("select f_ConsumerNO, f_ConsumerName from t_b_Consumer");

        while (ra.next()) {
            Map<String, String> dtnameN = new HashMap<String, String>();
            dtnameN.put("Numero", ra.getString("f_ConsumerNO"));
            dtnameN.put("Nombre", ra.getString("f_ConsumerName"));
            dataN.add(dtnameN);
        }
        ra.close();
        stUs.close();
```

por otra parte, tengo ésta otra colección que almacena las reservas de los socios:

```
Statement stn = miConexion.metodoConexionBD().createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stn.executeQuery("select * from Reservas where SalaID = " + 1 + " order by ID_Reserva Desc");
data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>() 

        while (rst.next()) {
            Map<String, String> dtname = new TreeMap<String, String>();
            dtname.put("Sala", rst.getString("SalaID"));
            dtname.put("Fecha", rst.getString("FechaReserva"));
            dtname.put("Hora1", rst.getString("HoraReserva"));
            dtname.put("Socio", rst.getString("SocioID"));
            dtname.put("Hora2", rst.getString("HoraReserva"));
            dtname.put("Hora3", rst.getString("HoraReserva"));
            data.add(dtname);
        }
        rst.close();
        stn.close();
```

Estoy intentando comparar los valores de numero en dataN y Socio en data

```
int mayor = dataN.size();
        if (data.size() > dataN.size()) {
            mayor = data.size();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mayor; i++){
            if (dataN.get(i).containsValue("Numero") == (data.get(i).containsValue("Socio"))){
                data.get(i).put("Socio", String.valueOf(dataN.get(i).containsValue("Nombre")));
            }
        }
```

La intentación sería, que en lugar de darme el número de socio almacenado en "data", me diera el nombre que corresponda a ese número de socio y está almacenado en "dataN", sustituyendo el número por el nombre en la colección "data", que es la que envío luego al listView

he dado con media solución, por fin he conseguido extraer los datos que necesito para realizar la comparación de valores

ahora me falta algo que quizás sea muy básico, pero que se me escapa, sería la iteración por todos los registros del hashmap

tengo el siguiente código, pero entro en un bucle del primer registro. No se como aumentar los ciclos del for. dtnameN.get("Numero"); Si le pongo dtnameN(i) me da error dtnameN.get("Numero"); Si le pongo dtnameN.get(i, "Numero") no lo admite Estoy algo perdido, alguna ayuda ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            String datoS1 = dtnameN.get("Numero");
            String dato1 = datoS1.replace(" ", "");
            String dato11 = dtnameN.get("Nombre");
            String dato2 = dtname.get("Socio");
            for (int j = 0; j < dataN.size(); j++) {
                if (dato1.equals(dato2)) {
                    data.get(j).put("Nombre", dato11);
                }
            }
        }
```

//en el primer for recorro el hashmap de las reservas.

//en datoS1 obtengo el numero del socio del primer hashmap.

//en dato1 elimino los espacios en blanco sw (datosS1) del número de socio del primer hashmap, pues de la base de datos, al tener 10 caracteres, me pone espacios donde no lo cubre el número.

//en dato11 obtengo el nombre del socio del primer hashmap.

//en dato2 obtengo el numero del socio del segundo hashmap.

//con el segundo for recorreria a todos los socios contenidos en el segundo hashmap.

//Compararía si los números de socio coinciden.

//Añadiría un nuevo valor al "Nombre" al segundo hashmap con el nombre del socio

Tras cambiar un poco el código, ahora me encuentro con algo que me descoloca

ahora pregunto directamente el número de socio enviando éste por parámetro al llamar al método

```
while (rst.next()) {
            dtname.put("Sala", rst.getString("SalaID"));
            dtname.put("Fecha", rst.getString("FechaReserva"));
            dtname.put("Hora1", rst.getString("HoraReserva"));
            dtname.put("Socio", rst.getString("SocioID"));
            String s = rst.getString("SocioID");
            dtname.put("Hora2", rst.getString("HoraReserva"));
            dtname.put("Hora3", rst.getString("HoraReserva"));
            String nombre = metodoObtenerNombre(s);
            dtname.put("Nombre", nombre);
            data.add(dtname);
        }
```

Pero en el método, es donde me deja de nuevo sin recursos, pues a pesar de hacer un bucle for para recorrer el arraylist de los socios, siempre me coge el mismo, o sea, ésta línea no está funcionando en la iteración del bucle (String dS1 = dataN.get(j).get("Numero");)

```
public String metodoObtenerNombre(String s){
    String nombre = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
        String dato2 = s;
        for (int j = 0; j < dataN.size(); j++) {
            String dS1 = dataN.get(j).get("Numero");
            String d1 = dS1.replace(" ", "");
            String dN = dataN.get(j).get("Nombre");
            if (dato2.equals(d1)) {
                nombre = dN;
            }
        }
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

Alguien me podría explicar que estoyy haciendo mal ? Un saludooooo

Un saludo